Incorrect TypeScript Type Inference with yarn build
This is my code in the layout component in the directory (auth)/dashboard:
interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export const AuthLayoutWrapper = ({ children }: Props) => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
      <DefaultLayout>
        {children}
      </DefaultLayout>
    </Suspense>
  );
};

When i run

yarn build

I get the error below:

.next/types/app/(dashboard)/layout.ts:8:13
Type error: Type 'OmitWithTag<typeof import("C:/Users/cross/Desktop/convertly.io/src/app/(dashboard)/layout"), "metadata" | "default" | "config" | "generateStaticParams" | "revalidate" | "dynamic" | "dynamicParams" | ... 6 more ... | "generateViewport", "">' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'.
Property 'AuthLayoutWrapper' is incompatible with index signature.
Type '({ children }: Props) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'never'.

 6 |
 7 | // Check that the entry is a valid entry
 8 | checkFields<Diff<{
   |             ^
 9 |   default: Function
10 |   config?: {}
11 |   generateStaticParams?: Function
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Environment

Next.js version: [14.2.3]
TypeScript version: [^5]
OS: [windows 10]


actually i'm not importing AuthLayoutWrapper anywhere else in the code. it's  just the laoyout component.  and it's not bein used anywhere else

Next.js expects your Layout (same for Page) Components to be default exported:

You can define a layout by default exporting a React component from a layout.js file.

Therefore you should simply do:
const AuthLayoutWrapper = // etc.

// Export your Component as default
export default AuthLayoutWrapper;

Or using the function notation, as shown in the Next.js docs, instead of arrow function:
export default function AuthLayoutWrapper({ children }: Props) {
  // etc.
}

The error message means that Next.js detects other named exports in your file, whereas it does not expect any other such export (hence the never type).
